# Get the part of the filename from list of files avoiding duplicates

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, grep

I have file "main.log" containing the list of filenames:

```
admin-dev.log
admin-prod.log
type1-app-dev-1.24.2.log
type1-app-dev-latest.log
type1-app-prod-1.24.2.log
type1-app-prod-1.24.3.log
type1-app-prod-latest.log
type2-app-stage-1.24.2.log
type2-app-dev-1.38.6.log
type2-app-dev-latest.log
type2-app-prod-1.38.6.log
type2-app-prod-1.38.7.log
type2-app-prod-latest.log
```

How to extract filenames from "main.log" file and print-out only version numbers relative to (type1 or type2), without duplicate versions?

Expected result from example above:

```
type1: 1.24.2
type1: 1.24.3
type1: latest
type2: 1.38.6
type2: 1.38.7
type2: latest
```

This is what I manage to do till now..

```
file_list="main.log";

# Read each line from the file
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [ "$line" != "$file_list" ]; then

        # filter type1
        ver1=$(echo "$line" | grep -o 'type1[^<]*' | sed -e 's/type1-app-\(.*\).apk/\1/');
        
        #filter type2
        ver2=$(echo "$line" | grep -o 'type2[^<]*' | sed -e 's/type2-app-\(.*\).apk/\1/');

        if [ "$ver1" ]; then
            echo "type1: $ver1";
        else
            echo "type2: $ver2";
        fi
    fi
done < $file_list
```

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Comment: For each entry in that file: Extract the initial part up to the dash, and also extract any sequence of digits and dots (for the version number).  This is probably easiest done with bash regular expressions. See the bash man-page and search for `=~`.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` + `sort` code. Written and tested with GNU `awk`. Using [`match`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function of GNU `awk` which has capability of creating capturing groups to be used their values in array to be accessed later on in program.

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/yCOcdb/1) for used regex.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/(^type[0-9]+)-[^-]*-[^-]*-([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+)\.log$/,arr){
  print arr[1]": "arr[2]
}
' Input_file | sort -u
```

***OR:*** In case you don't want to include string `latest` in output as per shown samples then try following code:

```bash
awk '
match($0,/(^type[0-9]+)-[^-]*-[^-]*-(.*)\.log$/,arr){
  print arr[1]": "arr[2]
}
' Input_file | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

```
sed -n 's/^\(type.\).*-\([^-]*\)\.log$/\1: \2/p' main.log | sort -u
```